# QtWebKit: Failed to addToJavaScriptWindowObject when two QWebView binding to one obj

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtwebkit

I have two `QWebView` instances(`webView1` and `webView2`), both of them have a same statement like this:

```
webView->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("JSCallable", parent);
```

which `parent` refers to a same instance that have public slots for JS to invoke(i.e. both `webView1` and `webView2` will call **the same method of the  same instance**), and I *do* call this statement whenever the webView(`webView1` and `webView2`) load a new URL;

---

Now the problem is: *only one* webView can call the method of `parent` successfully while the other cannot.

I wonder whether it is **possible** to binding two webView to one obj for the purpose that the JavaScript in different pages can call a same method of a `QObject`.

Any one would help? I will thank you in advance.

---

Qt 4.8.4 / VS2010 with Windows 7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trial of several times, i figured it out that it was **Possible** to do stuff above.

<strike>I think this problem should be closed.</strike>

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comment that i should post the answer, so just modify the answer:

Yes it is **Possible** to register two webView to one obj, you just do what you do when you have only one webView, I did it wrong somewhere in the first place and worked it out later.

*(Post it in case someone else encounter the same situation)*

Comment: If you found an answer, please post it here. That's the whole point of this site.

Comment: @mehaase just edit my post, trying to make it clear to everyone